# How to update a decoded JSON array with new array in PHP?

Tags: php, json, database

I need to know how to update a decoded JSON array with new values (I don't mean a simple `array_push` though).

I'm going to post my code, here's my `Users.json` file:

```
[
{
  "objID":"Y0FVVFZYCV",

  "createdOn":{"type":"__date","date":"2018-09-21T16:48:09"},
  "string":"lorem ipsum"
},
{
  "objID":"YShAUqIcMg",
  "username":"johndoe", // new key->value here!
  "createdOn":{"type":"__date","date":"2018-09-21T16:48:14"},
  "string":"lorem ipsum"
}
]
```

Here's my `create.php` file where I used to add JSON objects from a URL string:

```
// Prepare data to be saved:
if(!empty($_GET)){
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {

        // Random objID
        $objects->objID = generateRandomID();

        // Number       
        if( is_numeric($value) ){
            $objects->$key = (float) $value;

        // Boolean
        } else if($value === 'true'){
            $objects->$key = true;
        } else if($value === 'false'){
            $objects->$key = false;

        // ClassName
        } else if ($key === 'className'){

        // String
        } else { $objects->$key = $value; }


        // createdOn & updatedOn Dates
        $objects->createdOn = array('type'=>'__date','date'=>$formattedDate);
        $objects->updatedOn = array('type'=>'__date','date'=>$formattedDate);

    }// ./ foreach


    // Save data into the JSON file
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents($className.'.json');
    // Decode the JSON string into a PHP array.
    $jsonObjs = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

    // Check if there's some new key and values -> update the $jsonObjs array
    $result = array_diff($jsonObjs, $objects);
    print_r('<br><br>DIFFERENCE: <br>'.$result[0].'<br>');

    // Push array       
    array_push($jsonObjs, $objects);
    // Encode the array back into a JSON string and save it.
    $jsonData = json_encode($jsonObjs);
    file_put_contents($className.'.json', $jsonData);
    // echo JSON data
    echo $jsonData;
```

I'm trying to get the difference between `$jsonObjs` and `$objects` with `array_diff()`:

```
 $result = array_diff($jsonObjs, $objects);
 print_r(.$result[0].'<br>');
```

but it dones't work, it shows an empty row and also the error_log file shows this:

```
PHP Warning:  array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array on line 63
```

I launch 2 URL strings, the first one starts with

```
create.php?className=Users&string=lorem%20ipsum
```

In the 2nd one, I add an additional string object, like this:

```
create.php?className=Users&string=lorem%20ipsum&username=johndoe
```

So, what I need to achieve is to add the "username" key into the 1st object too, as it does on the 2nd object.  In other words, my `Users.json` file should look like this after launching the 2nd URL string:

```
[
    {
      "objID":"Y0FVVFZYCV",
      "username":"", //<-- upodated key with no value
      "createdOn":{"type":"__date","date":"2018-09-21T16:48:09"},
      "string":"lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
      "objID":"YShAUqIcMg",
      "username":"johndoe", // new key->value here!
      "createdOn":{"type":"__date","date":"2018-09-21T16:48:14"},
      "string":"lorem ipsum"
    }
    ]
```

Comment: As the error says, the second argument isn't an array. You've spent many lines treating it as an object, so you should know it's not an array!

Comment: well, i didn’t know that because my array_push() works fine, so i assumed that $objects was an array like $jsonObjs, otherwise how can array_push() work..?

Comment: `$objects->key`, `$objects->createdOn` this is not array syntax. The only instance of `array_push()` that I see is being applied to `$jsonObjs`, which is presumably an array. (Though it's worth mentioning you're not doing any error checking from `json_decode()` so it could just as easily be `null`.)

Comment: Is `$object` an instance of a class?from your syntax it's seems to be a class istance.

Comment: when i do array_push($jsonObjs, $objects), it adds $objects data to the $jsonObjs PHP array, so i’m a newbie on PHP, i thought that $objects is a PHP array as well, otherwise how can $objects be added to $jsonObjs? $objects gets data from a URL string launched from my browser like create.php?username=johndoe&string=lorem ipsum

Comment: @miken32 yes, $jsonObjs is an array decoded from my Users.json file

Comment: There's no reason an object can't be added as an item in an array. An array is just a collection of things. They can be integers, strings, objects, or other arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out in the comments, you can't pass "$objects" to the array_diff function because it expects an array and "$objects" is, well, an Object.

You *could* cast your object to an array by calling it like this:

```
$result = array_diff($jsonObjs, (array)$objects);
```

Comment: not yet, sorry, because it still echoes nothing, so your solution doesn’t work. maybe i should json_decode)$objects)?

Comment: nope, even if i json_decode() it doesn’t work, it prints nothing as $result

Comment: what shows if you var_dump($result) right after the array_diff call?

Comment: still nothing, i guess i have to convert stdClass Object into a PHP array, if i print_r $objects i get: stdClass Object(...)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out my @miken32, my $objects object wasn't an array, but an StdClass Object, so I simply had to replace:

```
$objects->
```

with:

```
$objects[$key]
```

In this way, `$objects` becomes a valid array and I can use array_diff() like this:

```
$result = array_diff_assoc($jsonObjs, $objects);
print_r('DIFF: '.json_encode($result).'<hr>');
```

It prints out a valid JSON array.